# Files are missing in local machine but are in Repo

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm having some issues with getting git and my local machine to work. The issue is that the projects code is living in ADO (Azure DevOps). I created a branch to work on a feature but when pushing the changes and creating a PR and merging such PR to master branch, some of the files went missing. An example would be that I have a WPF app and the views have a .xaml and a .xaml.cs file but one file has the .xaml but not the .xaml.cs. It just appears that it is missing. Which makes no sense to me since I can see it in the repo. I tried creating another PR but git mentions that theres nothing to merge. Try manually merging the branch but it mentions that there's nothing to update. Has anyone experience this issue?